# Is it possible to get notified by email of questions that reach a certain threshold of popularity?

Tags: support, notifications

I'm hoping to use Information Security as resource to stay on top of newly released, wide-affecting security vulnerabilities when they become released. Unfortunately I don't have the capacity to be checking Information Security once/twice/thrice daily.

**Is there anyway to have Information Security notify me by email once a question reaches a certain number of up votes?**

**Or should I just take off and find an email list to join?**

Thanks.

Comment: Definitely better finding a few good mailing lists and/or Twitter feeds. Once in a while, we'll get a question about some big vulnerability out here. But that's usually well after the news has broken elsewhere and they're not always highly upvoted. 'Round here, following a feed of questions with a high up-vote velocity is more useful for hopping on a "rep train" than actually catching hot news items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the exact functionality you want to provide notification of highly upvoted questions doesn't exist here, but then even if it did it wouldn't provide you with what you want. There will only be a few of these questions which will be news of new infosec information.

That said, you can always look at the recent questions page sorted by votes and that will show you what is highly upvoted.

If you want a notification of new exploits, research, news etc., then you'd be better of signing up for one of the infosec news lists.